# How to check auth user in laravel subdomain?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a project it's Backend is built in Laravel 5.2 and Frontend is built in PHP. Please check the folder structure below it's in localhost.

**Backend : http://crm.test.dev This is the root folder, laravel5.2 -> public ->index.php**

**Frontend: http://test.dev This url is point to laravel5.2 -> public -> frontend -> index.php**

My purpose is, If a user(admin) is logged in Backend(http://crm.test.dev) and not signed out. The same user is accessing Frontend(http://test.dev") at that time I need to show an alert you are logged in Backend(http://crm.test.dev).

**frontend->index.php**

```
require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app      = require_once __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel   = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$isAuthorized = Auth::check();
$user         = Auth::user();
echo $user;
```

Comment: are using Routes to manage sub-domains ? I mean same Routes.php

Comment: @jaysingkar not using routes http://test.dev is frontend and It is built in core php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually issue is from config -> session.php `{'domain' => null,}`. I updated this line to `{ 'domain' => '.test.dev', }` . Now a user is logged in backend and accessing frontend (subdomain: http://test.dev) `"Your are logged in"` message shows.

```
require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app      = require_once __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel   = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$isAuthorized = Auth::check();
$user         = Auth::user();

if(Auth::check()) {
    echo "Your are logged in";
}
else {
    echo "Sorry";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to the sites you've posted. But you can check if the users logged in with `Auth::check()` as you already do. Then you can do it e.g. like this:

```
if(Auth::check()) {
    echo "You're locked in";
    //do some action
else {
    //do normal action
}
```

Comment: P. Barth, Thanks for you reply. Actually issue is from config -> session.php {'domain' => null,}. I updated this line to { 'domain' => '.test.dev', }.

Comment: So you fixed the problem?